# Discrete random variables and independent events

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable. The probability function is given in the following table

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
x&-10&1&5&10\\ \hline
f(x)&0.1&0.3&0.4&0.2
\end{array}
$$

I wish to compute probability function for discrete random variable $Y$ such that $Y=X^2$

If I want to know $f(100)$, then

$$
\begin{align*}
f(100)=P(Y=100)=P(X^2=100)&=P(\{X=10\}\cup\{X=-10\})\\
&=P(X=10)+P(X=-10)-P(\{X=10\}\cap\{X=-10\})\\
&=0.2+0.1-0\\
&=0.3
\end{align*}
$$
Why the events $\{X=10\}$ and $\{X=-10\}$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not independent, they are mutually exclusive. Events $A$ and $B$ are independent if
$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B) $$
$A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if
$$ P(A \cap B) = 0 $$
$\{X = 10\}$ and $\{X = -10\}$ are mutually exclusive since we can't simultaneously have $X = 10$ and $X = -10$.

Comment: Why can not we have simultaneously $X=10$ and $X=-10$?

Comment: Because $\{X = 10\}$ and $\{X = -10\}$ are different events. $X$ can only have one value. It's like you can't have a coin flip be simultaneously heads and tails. An example of two events that aren't mutually exclusive are $\{X = 10\ \text{or}\ X = 1\}$ and $\{X = 1\ \text{or}\ X = -10\}$, since if $X = 1$ both events occur.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't independent because $$P(\{X=10\} \cap \{X=-10\}) \ne P(\{X=10\}) P(\{X=-10\}).$$

- $P(\{X=10\} \cap \{X=-10\}) = P(\varnothing) = 0$
- $P(\{X=10\}) P(\{X=-10\}) = 0.2 \times 0.1 > 0$

Comment: Why $P(\{X=10\} \cap \{X=-10\}) = P(\varnothing) = 0$?

Comment: @ThomasHiler $$\{X=10\} \cap \{X=-10\} = \varnothing$$ since $X: \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$ is a function, so it can't map $\omega \in \Omega$ into two disjoint subset of $\Bbb{R}$.